# How to get rid of double selection thing in ListView (XAML)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a `ListView` and I bind to an `ObservableCollection<Folder>` and when I hover over a `ListViewItem`, there is a second selection thing appearing underneath (or ontop of) the item text which prevents me from being able to "activate" the selected item because it doesn't appear to be receiving my click.

[image]

As you can probably see, the structure is:

`ListView` > `ItemTemplate` > `DataTemplate` > `ListViewItem`. But I'm guessing I have that double-selection thing because there are basically 2 "item templates" (`DataTemplate` and `ItemTemplate`). But if I get rid of `DataTemplate`, it throws a runtime error. If I get rid of `ItemTemplate`, it throws an error. I can't win. How do I get rid of this thing?

---

*Update*:

This gives me the desired effect:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="folderContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="175" Background="Khaki" Margin="0, 18, 0, 0">
    <ListView x:Name="folderList" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Folder}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="folderItem" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Do you need the overhead of the `ListViewItem` (with all its visual states), could you just use a `TextBlock`?

Comment: Use a `ListBox` if all you intend to show is just one field?

Comment: Don't use `ListViewItem` as the root visual of `DataTemplate` (which is again set as ItemTemplate of a ListView). That of course causes the strange effect as you see.

Comment: @KingKing Is it just me or does it seem weird that there appears to be no way to bind ListViewItems without DataTemplate and ItemTemplate without those weird things there?

Comment: Thanks @KingKing and sa_ddam213, you were right. I removed ListViewItem and went with a TextBlock and it's now giving me the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `ListViewItem` you where including a specialized wrapper primarily used the `ListView` to contain unknown item(s) presented by the binding of the ItemsSource when there is default template used. It helps *to show* that unknown item on the screen, its the purpose of the `ListViewItem`. For example if someone bound a list of strings, the strings have no *xaml style* on hover, hence there needs to be a container control to achieve all things graphical in those situations.

### Why the two Shadows?

The actual [ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listviewitem(v=vs.110).aspx) is at its heart (or actually its property), a [content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx) control containing *what I surmise you had* was a textbox control. That is *now* two controls thanks to the DataTemplate you provided.

Hence you had a wrapper, with a content containing a texbox control. So there are two things which take up space, one is the `ListViewItem` and the other is the textbox. By hovering over each item, each's style kicked off to show the padding of the control as a selectable region in the Zorder fashion whereas both are seen.

Nothing more nothing less.

Since *you* knew what is to go into the content control, there was no need to use the `ListViewItem` wrapper, it was redundant, and you used the actual textbox; hence with only it's style to show the padding of the *single* control on hover.